# MD5 encryption java / mysql. in Java MD5 generates 31 bytes instead of 32

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, md5

i have a php script to insert a username and md5(password) in my database with a mysql query ( for registration function), and a script that select the username and password ( for login function).

For the registration , i send the data from my android application, the password that i send is not encryipted. Php script make the encryption with the mysql function md5("password").

For the login, i send the encrypted password ( from the app) .

My problem was that there is a byte of difference between the java's MD5 and the mysql's MD5.

For example i have stored in my db this md5 password ( made by mysql'md5) :

```
 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

and java make this md5:

```
 90150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

another example : 
mysql-->      0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
java -->      cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661

I can made all the md5 encryption in java , or all in mysql, but I want to understand the reason for this difference.

this is my MD5 codifier in java :

```
/**
 * Utility class for MD5 management.
 *
 * @author Massimo Carli - Jul 12, 2013
 */
public final class MD5Utility {

    /*
     * The FF value.
     */
    private static final int FF_HEX_VALUE = 0xFF;

    // Private constructor
    private MD5Utility() {
        throw new AssertionError("Never instantiate this!");
    }

    /**
     * Calculate MD5 for String src.
     *
     * @param src The string to check
     * @return MD5 for src or null if some error occured
     */
    public static String md5(String src) {
        try {
            // Create MD5 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(src.getBytes());
            byte[] messageDigest = digest.digest();
            // Create Hex String
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(FF_HEX_VALUE & messageDigest[i]));
            }
            String md5 = hexString.toString();
            return md5;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check a String with its MD5.
     *
     * @param str The string
     * @param md5 The MD5 to check
     * @return true if ok, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean checkMD5(String str, String md5) {
        String pwdMD5 = md5(str);
        // We return the test
        boolean success = md5.equals(pwdMD5);
        return success;
    }

}
```

Can someone help me? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: why dont you md5 in php instead of doing it in java and sending it to php

Comment: Avoid md5 and look into something like blowfish

Comment: @IndraKumarS if i send the password not encrypted from my phone, what about security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method in java. This method give same hash as mysql md5.

```
public static String getMD5Hash(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

String result = s;
if (s != null) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); // or "SHA-1"
    md.update(s.getBytes());
    BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
    result = hash.toString(16);
    while (result.length() < 32) { // 40 for SHA-1
        result = "0" + result;
    }
}
return result; }
```

Comment: why you add the "0" ? ( i know that is always a 0 missing). 
i'd like to know why is missing always the 0 char.

Comment: This site will help understanding why. maybe http://www.logikdev.com/2012/12/12/md5-generates-31-bytes-instead-of-32/